unattended-upgr causing my EC2 instance to become unresponsive and terminate
I'm running a service inside a Docker container on a t4g.nano instance (with 512 MB RAM). My services typically use around 65% of memory, and they seem to be running fine most of the time, however, every once in a while, I can see spikes on memory and CPU usage. When checking through journalctl, I can see this:
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: Tasks state (memory values in pages):
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [  pid  ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [    150]     0   150    12106      928   102400        0          -250 systemd-journal
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [    190]     0   190    72415     6464   114688        0         -1000 multipathd
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [    193]     0   193     2736      956    65536        0         -1000 systemd-udevd
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [    351]   100   351     4102      832    81920        0             0 systemd-network
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [    353]   101   353     6307     1616    94208        0             0 systemd-resolve
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [    397]     0   397      557      384    40960        0             0 acpid
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [    402]     0   402     1727      480    57344        0             0 cron
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [    403]   102   403     2214      832    69632        0          -900 dbus-daemon
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [    410]     0   410    20520      640    61440        0             0 irqbalance
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [    411]     0   411     8238     2816   114688        0             0 networkd-dispat
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [    413]   104   413    55505      992    90112        0             0 rsyslogd
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [    414]     0   414   457784     2090   200704        0             0 amazon-ssm-agen
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [    417]     0   417   348223     3230   262144        0          -900 snapd
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [    418]     0   418     3889      800    77824        0             0 systemd-logind
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [    448]     0   448   446710     3840   262144        0          -999 containerd
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [    454]     0   454     1408      448    49152        0             0 agetty
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [    457]     0   457     1397      352    49152        0             0 agetty
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [    481]   115   481     5072     1426    73728        0             0 pgbouncer
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [    567]   114   567     4654      579    61440        0             0 chronyd
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [    585]   114   585     2557      427    61440        0             0 chronyd
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [    636]     0   636    27483     2688   122880        0             0 unattended-upgr
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [    676]     0   676    58833     1006    98304        0             0 polkitd
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [    772]     0   772   489411     6641   348160        0          -500 dockerd
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [    807]     0   807     3785     1024    73728        0         -1000 sshd
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [    978]     0   978   309497      862   118784        0          -998 containerd-shim
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [    998] 65534   998   308899     1608   122880        0             0 pgbouncer_expor
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [   1753]     0  1753    74364     1408   176128        0             0 packagekitd
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [   3689]     0  3689      576      352    45056        0             0 apt.systemd.dai
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [   3693]     0  3693      576      352    45056        0             0 apt.systemd.dai
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [   3721]     0  3721    85333    15613   458752        0             0 unattended-upgr
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: [   3913]     0  3913   102053    31125   479232        0             0 unattended-upgr
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=init.scope,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/system.slice/apt-daily>
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 3913 (unattended-upgr) total-vm:408212kB, anon-rss:121788kB, file-rss:2712kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:0 p>
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.service: A process of this unit has been killed by the OOM killer.
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM
Sep 23 06:31:10 ip-xxxxx systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'

This doesn't always cause the instance to stop responding, but it can happen sometimes. This can also sometimes cause the instance to terminate and get replaced (I'm using an Auto Scaling Group) which is bad for our use case.
PS: Please don't be too hard on me, I'm relatively new to Linux and managing servers.

It seems like your t4g.nano instance is running into memory limitations, leading to the Out of Memory (OOM) killer terminating processes. The instance only has 512 MB of RAM, and even though your services typically use around 65%, occasional spikes are causing memory exhaustion.
In the specific case you mentioned, the apt-daily-upgrade.service was killed due to memory overload. This is likely happening during automated package updates, which can be resource-intensive.
Here are some potential solutions:

Disable or schedule updates: You can disable the apt-daily-upgrade.service to prevent it from running automatically or schedule it to run at a less critical time when memory usage is lower.
To disable it:

sudo systemctl disable apt-daily-upgrade.service apt-daily.service
sudo systemctl mask apt-daily-upgrade.service apt-daily.service


Reduce memory usage of background services:
Consider reducing the memory footprint of other background services (e.g., by disabling or optimizing logging, reducing unnecessary services like packagekitd or polkitd).

Optimize your Docker container's memory usage:
Ensure your container uses as little memory as possible. You can set memory limits for Docker containers to avoid using more memory than necessary:


docker run --memory=128m --memory-swap=128m <your_container>


Swap space: Add swap space to the instance to handle occasional memory spikes. This is useful when RAM runs out:

sudo fallocate -l 1G /swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
sudo sh -c 'echo "/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0" >> /etc/fstab'

These steps should help mitigate memory issues and reduce the frequency of OOM kills.
